# Can we use "import" keyword when running nodejs v10?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I'm asking if is it possible to use some of new ES features when running node v10,
when I tried to use the "import" keywords it throws error:

```
import  os from 'os';

console.log(os);
```

when I run it I got:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import  os from 'os';
                                                                      ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
```

which ES spec nodejs 10 support ?

Comment: Have you heared of Babel?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know the new features that are supported by the new nodejs version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few routes. #1, enable experimental module support (Which came in [v9](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/esm.html)), and rename your file with a `.mjs` extension:

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

Enable [babel transpilation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/), using `babel-node`:

```
babel-node index.js
```

Comment: it's ok with babel, but I want to know the features that are supported directly by nodejs v10

Comment: @maroodb `import` is not valid syntax in v10 (Without enabling experimental modules). You need to use babel/webpack or some other type of transpiler to compile the code down to be supported for v10 without enabling the experimental modules. I highly suggest checking out my open source chatexchange library which demonstrates how this can be accomplished [here](https://github.com/danbopes/chatexchange).

Comment: it I understood, nodejs 10 LTS is built on v10 and support just es6 spec ?

Comment: @maroodb Since v9 (I've updated my answer), they've enabled experimental module support, but it's something that has to specifically be enabled while executing node.

Comment: OK. using which version of nodejs can we use "import" keyword without babel ?

Comment: v9 and above, using the experimental modules feature